# The returned code not stopping on ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vb.net

this is my ajax call function

```
$.ajax({
    url: "webservices/mywebserveice.vb",
    data: "{'myactivity':'" + myactivity + "','myproddate':'" + mynewprddatee + "'}",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
        //obj[0]["ColumnName"]
        var returnlist = new Array();
```

my vb. code  returns some data and pass I to ajax call using 
`Return New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(rows)` .It stops at `var obj` in ajax call for some data but it is not stopping when i pass some other data in vb file. even if i have identical dataset result.

here is a part of vb code

```
   'Convert Dataset to DataReader
        Dim dr As DataTableReader = ds.Tables(0).CreateDataReader()

        If dr.HasRows Then
            Do While dr.Read()
                row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
                For c As Integer = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1  '//fieldcount gives the column count.
                    row.Add(dr.GetName(c), dr.GetValue(c)) '//getname->gets the column name; getvalue->gets the col value.
                Next
                rows.Add(row)
            Loop
        End If

        Return New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(rows)
```

I also tried `asycn = false/ture` , same issue ..

Any help appreciate

Comment: Depends entirely on the data you're sending through. Is it in the correct format? Are there any characters in the data that are being misread or causing the javascript function to crash? Test the program with both working and failing data, find a pattern.

Comment: They really look identical but since it is a big data , I ll recheck it again . it looked me because of same reason but I couldn't find any different part of t.

Comment: There's likely some character hiding in there that the client side function doesn't like... Like dates. dates always cause problems.

Comment: :) ok I ll check it again let you know. Thanks

Comment: I checked dates and other , they look fine but only difference is ,  working one has 143 array sort but not working one has 168 array sort . does this make any problem ?

Comment: do you mean 168 elements in the array?

Comment: yes. I just updated my question. What I meant is in 'rows' it has 168 row which is not working and cant pass it to ajax call ,but  143 rows is working and pass it to ajax call.

Comment: might want to post the actually values in the array here...

Comment: you all right ,. it was data issue.  I  recompiled sp with the corrected data in the table.Did work,  Thanks guys.